# How do I use socket.io and express together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I've got a problem with socket.io emit and express. I want to emit some data (I'm creating a webgame) so I need to emit players data to a specific lobby. For example I create a lobby at this link: 
localhost:8000/test/lobbyName 
and I need to emit information only to this lobby and no to the others. How I can do that?

this is my code:

www

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('progetto:server');
var http = require('http');
/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//Game
let players = {};

let xCoin = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1200));

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('A user connected');

  players[socket.id] = {
      rotation: 0,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      layer: Math.floor((Math.random() * -1200)),
      playerId: socket.id,
      frame: 0,
      haveGun: true,

  };

  socket.emit('currentPlayers', players);

  socket.broadcast.emit('newPlayer', players[socket.id]);

  socket.emit('newCoin',  xCoin);

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('User disconnected');

      delete players[socket.id];

      io.emit('disconnect', socket.id);

  });

  socket.on('playerMovement', function (movementData) {
      players[socket.id].x = movementData.x;
      players[socket.id].y = movementData.y;
      players[socket.id].layer = movementData.layer;
      players[socket.id].frame = movementData.frame;

      socket.broadcast.emit('playerMoved', players[socket.id]);

  });

  socket.on('playerAngle', function (movementData) {
      socket.broadcast.emit('gunAngle', socket.id, movementData);

  });

  socket.on('playerShotting', function (movementData) {
      socket.broadcast.emit('shotting', socket.id, movementData);

  });

  socket.on('coinTaken', function (x, y) {
      socket.broadcast.emit('taken', x, y);

  });

  socket.on('createGun', function (n1, n2) {
      socket.broadcast.emit('enemyGun', players[socket.id].playerId, n1, n2);

  });

})





/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

main.js

```
let game = new Phaser.Game(
    {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
        physics:  {
            default: 'arcade',
            arcade:   {
                debug: false,
                gravity: { y: 0 }

            }
        },
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update

        }
});

let playerInfo = ['Daniel', 100, 100, 3, 12, 1000];       //nickname , gold, life , jump , spead , gravity

let player =  new Player(game, playerInfo);
let background =  new Background();
let settings = new Settings();

function preload () {
    load(this);

    loading(this);

    settings.preload();
}

function create () {
    let playerArray = [0, 0];

    this.socket = io();

    player.debug(this);

    var self = this;

    this.otherPlayers = this.physics.add.group();

    this.socket.on('currentPlayers', function (players) {
        Object.keys(players).forEach(function (id) {
            if (players[id].playerId === self.socket.id) {
                player.createPlayer(self, players[id]);

            }else if(playerArray[0] == 0) {
                playerArray[0] = players[id].playerId;
                player.createEnemyOne(self, players[id]);

            }else if(playerArray[1] == 0) {
                playerArray[1] = players[id].playerId;
                player.createEnemyTwo(self, players[id]);

            }else {
                playerArray[2] = players[id].playerId;
                player.createEnemyTre(self, players[id]);

            }
        });
    });

    this.socket.on('newPlayer', function (playerInfo) {
        if(playerArray[0] == 0) {
            playerArray[0] = playerInfo.playerId;
            player.createEnemyOne(self, playerInfo);

        }else if(playerArray[1] == 0) {
            playerArray[1] = playerInfo.playerId;
            player.createEnemyTwo(self, playerInfo);

        }else {
            playerArray[2] = playerInfo.playerId;
            player.createEnemyTre(self, playerInfo);

        }
    });

    this.socket.on('disconnect', function (playerId) {
        self.otherPlayers.getChildren().forEach(function (otherPlayer) {
            if(playerId === otherPlayer.playerId) {
                otherPlayer.destroy();
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                if(playerId == playerArray[i]) {
                    playerArray[i] = 0;

                }
            }
        });
    });

    this.socket.on('playerMoved', function (playerInfo) {
        if(playerArray[0] == playerInfo.playerId) {
            move = playerInfo.layer - background.midle.x;
            player.setPosition(player.enemy, player.gun1,player.textEn1, playerInfo.x - move, playerInfo.y * window.innerHeight, playerInfo.frame, player.haveGun1);

        }else if(playerArray[1] == playerInfo.playerId) {
            move = playerInfo.layer - background.midle.x;
            player.setPosition(player.enemy2, player.gun2, player.textEn2, playerInfo.x - move, playerInfo.y * window.innerHeight, playerInfo.frame, player.haveGun2);

        }else {
            move = playerInfo.layer - background.midle.x;
            player.setPosition(player.enemy3, player.gun3, player.textEn3, playerInfo.x - move, playerInfo.y * window.innerHeight, playerInfo.frame, player.haveGun3);

        }
    });

    this.input.on('pointermove', function (pointer) {
        if(player.haveGun) {
            let angle = (Phaser.Math.Angle.Between(player.player.x , player.player.y, pointer.x , pointer.y)) * (180/Math.PI);
            player.gun_angle(angle + 90);

        }
    });

    this.socket.on('gunAngle', function (id, playerInfo) {
        if(playerArray[0] == id) {
            if(player.haveGun1) player.gunAngle(player.gun1, playerInfo.angle);

        }else if(playerArray[1] == id) {
            if(player.haveGun2) player.gunAngle(player.gun2, playerInfo.angle);

        }else {
            if(player.haveGun3) player.gunAngle(player.gun3, playerInfo.angle);

        }
    });

    this.socket.on('shotting', function (id, playerInfo) {
        if(playerArray[0] == id) {
            player.shot(self.bulletsEnemy, player.enemy, playerInfo);

        }else if(playerArray[1] == id) {
            player.shot(self.bulletsEnemy2,player.enemy2,  playerInfo);

        }else {
            player.shot(self.bulletsEnemy3,player.enemy3,  playerInfo);

        }
      });

      this.socket.on('newCoin', function (x) {
          background.worldObject.createCoin(self, x, true);

      });

      this.socket.on('taken', function (x, y) {
          background.worldObject.coin.destroy();
          background.worldObject.createCoin(self, x, y);

      });

      this.socket.on('enemyGun', function (id, info, info2) {
        if(playerArray[0] == id) {
            player.enemyGun1(self, info, info2);
        }else if(playerArray[1] == id) {
            player.enemyGun2(self, info, info2);
        }else {
            player.enemyGun3(self, info, info2);
        }

      });

      background.createBackground(this);

      settings.create(this);

}

function loading(game) {
    let progressBar = game.add.graphics();
    let progressBox = game.add.graphics();
    let width = 320, heigth = 50;
    progressBox.fillStyle(0x222222, 0.8);
    progressBox.fillRect(window.innerWidth / 2 - (width / 2), window.innerHeight / 2 - (heigth / 2), width, heigth);

    let loadingText = game.make.text({
        x: window.innerWidth / 2,
        y: window.innerHeight / 2 - 50,
        text: 'Loading...',
        style: {
            font: '20px monospace',
            fill: '#ffffff'
        }
    });

    let percentText = game.make.text({
        x: window.innerWidth / 2,
        y: window.innerHeight / 2 - 5,
        text: '0%',
        style: {
            font: '18px monospace',
            fill: '#ffffff'
        }
    });

    let assetText = game.make.text({
        x: window.innerWidth / 2 - 100,
        y: window.innerHeight / 2 + 50,
        text: '',
        style: {
            font: '18px monospace',
            fill: '#ffffff'
        }
    });

    percentText.setOrigin(0.5, 0.5);

    loadingText.setOrigin(0.5, 0.5);

    game.load.on('progress', function (value) {
        progressBar.clear();
        progressBar.fillStyle(0xffffff, 1);
        progressBar.fillRect(window.innerWidth / 2 - ((width - 20) / 2), window.innerHeight / 2 - ((heigth - 20) / 2), 300 * value, heigth - 20);

        percentText.setText(parseInt(value * 100) + '%');

    });

    game.load.on('fileprogress', function (file) {
      console.log(file.key);
        assetText.setText('Loading asset: ' + file.key);

    });

    game.load.on('complete', function () {
        progressBar.destroy();
        progressBox.destroy();
        loadingText.destroy();
        percentText.destroy();
        assetText.destroy();

    });
}

function load(game) {

    let playerImg = ['/images/snowman.png', '/images/snowman.png', '/images/snowman.png', '/images/snowman.png'];

    let sound = ['/sounds/Jump.mp3', '/sounds/Explosion.mp3', '/sounds/Pickup_Coin.mp3']

    let groundImg = ['/images/ground.png','/images/nuvola.png', '/images/map.json', '/images/coin.png', '/images/heart.png', '/images/pozioni.png'];

    game.load.spritesheet('player', playerImg[0], { frameWidth: 128, frameHeight: 128 });
    game.load.spritesheet('enemy', playerImg[1], { frameWidth: 128, frameHeight: 128 });
    game.load.spritesheet('enemy2', playerImg[2], { frameWidth: 128, frameHeight: 128 });
    game.load.spritesheet('enemy3', playerImg[3], { frameWidth: 128, frameHeight: 128 });

    game.load.audio('jumpAudio', sound[0]);
    game.load.audio('shotAudio', sound[1]);
    game.load.audio('coinAudio', sound[2]);

    game.load.image("tiles1", groundImg[0]);
    game.load.image("tiles2", groundImg[1]);
    game.load.tilemapTiledJSON("map", groundImg[2]);

    game.load.spritesheet("coin", groundImg[3], { frameWidth: 128, frameHeight: 128 });
    game.load.spritesheet("heart", groundImg[4], { frameWidth: 128, frameHeight: 128 });
    game.load.spritesheet("pozions", groundImg[5], { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 32 });

}

function update () {
    if(player.life != false)  player.update(this);

    background.update(this);

    background.midle.setCollisionByProperty({colision:true});

    this.physics.add.collider(player.player, background.midle);

}

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    game.scale.setGameSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    background.midle.displayHeight = window.innerHeight;

    player.resize();

    settings.resize();

});
```

Then I want to let the user create their rooms, so I followed a tutorial that I found and that's the code in my index.js file:

```
router.get('/test/:id', function(req, res, next){
  res.render('test', {output: req.params.id} );
})

router.post('/test/submit', function(req, res, next){
  var id = req.body.id;
  res.redirect('/test/' + id);
})
```

and this is the the form:

```html
<form action="/test/submit" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="id">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now, how can I use socket.io to emit players data only to the redirect page that the player is connected?

Sorry for my poor english, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of `socket.io` [rooms or namespaces](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/).

**Rooms**

On socket connection, join the socket to a specific room, in your case: `lobbyName` for example, and then emit only to that room

```
io.to('lobbyName').emit(...)
```

**Namespaces**

On the backend, create one namespace per lobby.

```
const lobbies = ['/lobbyName'];

for(const lobby of lobbies) {
    const nsp = io.of(lobby);
    // Your socket logic in here
    nsp.on('connection', socket => {
      console.log('someone connected');
    });
}
```

And connect to that specific namespace in the front end:

```
const socket = io('/lobbyName');
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try with this method. I edited my question, can you help me more?

Comment: You shouldn't edit a question and add extra things after the original question has been answered. Always create a new question for it.

Comment: ok, sorry but I'm new... I create the new question, thank you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58982887/game-lobby-with-socket-io-and-express)