# Game lobby with socket.io and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm creating a web game using socket.io and express.
I want to let users create their lobby and I want to use socket.io to emit data (position, etc...) only to the lobby that they're connected. How can I do it? 
For the moment I found this code online but it emit data to all the lobby that are created.

index.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Create lobby',
    errors: req.session.errors
  });
  req.session.errors = null;
});

router.get('/lobby/:id', function(req, res, next){
  res.render('test', {output: req.params.id} );
})

router.post('/lobby/submit', function(req, res, next){
  var id = req.body.id;
  res.redirect('/lobby/' + id);
})

module.exports = router;
```

index.html

```
<form action="/lobby/submit" method="post">
  <input type="lobby" name="id">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is a lobby in your code?  And, where do you want to emit to it?  You don't show any data structure that represents a lobby.  Further is a lobby something that is unique to that user or is it a shared resource and multiple users may need notifications related to it?  I'm wondering if you can use the socket.io concept of a `room` to be a lobby.  In socket.io a room can be for 1 to n users and it's easy to send data to everyone in that room.  The server decides which sockets are in that room.

Comment: well, I found this code on the internet and it do this: it redirect user to a html page with url localhost:8000/lobby/userInput, that's all

Comment: Well, there's not enough here to know what you're trying to do.  I've tried to help, but still have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.